# "Как мало осталось от ПРЕЖНЕЙ ЛЮБИМОЙ РОДНОЙ Москвы." Все ли прилагательные однородные?

Tags: пунктуация

"Как мало осталось от прежней любимой родной Москвы." По-моему, прилагательные здесь неоднородные.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как мало осталось от прежней, любимой, родной Москвы.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

В данном случае определения можно считать однородными, так как они имеют сближенные значения (таким образом создается единый образ прежней Москвы).

Comment: Б  л  а  г  о д  а  р  ю  !

Answer (score 4):

***Как мало осталось от прежней любимой, родной Москвы!***
Любимой, родной - однородные определения, характеризующие предмет с одной стороны.

Возможен ещё один вариант оформления этого предложения:
***Как мало осталось от прежней - любимой, родной - Москвы!*** Вставная констркция с однородными определениями уточняет и поясняет определение ПРЕЖНЕЙ.

Comment: Первый вариант вызывает большие сомнения. Любимой, родной - однородные определения. Попробуем оставить только одно из них: Как мало осталось от прежней любимой Москвы. Странное предложение: относительное прилагательное находится перед качественным, да и смысл непонятный. Кажется,  автор называет любимой и родной именно прежнюю Москву. Второй вариант возможен, но сложно выглядит. То же самое можно сказать, считая все определения однородными.

Comment: С  п  а  с  и  б  о  !